# How to add a button in the header of a table form?

Tags: 8, forms

I have this table form:
[image]

The corresponding code for the header is

```
$form['inscriptions'] = [
  '#type'   => 'table',
  '#header' => [
    [
      'data'    => '',
      'colspan' => 2,
    ],
    [
      'data'    => 'Distribution',
      'colspan' => 2,
    ],
    [
      'data'    => 'Réserve',
      'colspan' => 2,
    ],
    [
      'data'    => 'Référent',
      'colspan' => 2,
    ],
  ],
  '#id'     => 'planningofdistributions',
  '#sticky' => TRUE,
];
```

I would like to replace the (empty) content of the first cell by a submit button.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it this way:

```
if (some condition) {
  $data = [
    '#type'     => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '<input type="submit" id="edit-toggle" name="button" value="{{ foo }}" class="button js-form-submit form-submit">',
    '#context'  => ['foo' => $this->t('Toggle')],
  ];
}
else {
  $data = '';
}

$form['inscriptions'] = [
  '#type'   => 'table',
  '#header' => [
    [
      'data'    => $data,
      'colspan' => 2,
    ],
    [
      'data'    => 'Distribution',
      'colspan' => 2,
    ],
    [
      'data'    => 'Réserve',
      'colspan' => 2,
    ],
    [
      'data'    => 'Référent',
      'colspan' => 2,
    ],
  ],
  '#id'     => 'planningofdistributions',
  '#sticky' => TRUE,
];
```